# nhibernate: Class Mapping with no table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an entity class that I use to represent the results of an sql-query. The mapping for the class shown below. Yet as far as I can tell nhiberate treats the mapping as if there is a real database table - when in fact there is not. In this case there is nothing in the database that represents this entity at all. I am using this to map a query through, but the same would be true of a view. Is there no way to indicate to nhibernate that there isn't a table represented by the mapping?

```
<class name="Models.UserTransaction"> <!-- Defaults table name same as Entity even though table doesn’t exist -->
  <id name="Id">
    <column name="Id" not-null="true" unique="true" />
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="TransType" />
  <property name="Date" />
  <property name="Amount" />
  <property name="Balance" />
</class>
```

This is the query I am mapping, which uses a user defined table. I couldn't get it working without having a mapping even though the example I copied appeared to.

```
  <sql-query name="UserTransactions">
    <query-param name="userId" type="string" />
    <return class="Models.UserTransaction" alias="userTx">
      <return-property name="TransType" column="TransType" />
      <return-property name="Id" column="Id" />
      <return-property name="Date" column="TransDate" />
      <return-property name="Amount" column="Amount" />
      <return-property name="Balance" column="Balance" />
    </return>
    <![CDATA[
      SELECT userTx.[Type] as TransType, userTx.[Id] as Id, userTx.[Date] as TransDate, userTx.[Amount] as Amount, userTx.[Balance] as Balance
      FROM dbo.User_AccountStatement(:userId) userTx
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
```

Comment: If you don't want to map your class to the database, then.. why are you mapping it? :) just remove the mapping completely, tell nHib to not map it, and that's it

Comment: As the question says I want to map it to the results of a query, like a report, so a one way (i.e. database to application) mapping. Just seems wrong for nhibernate to think treat it like a two way mapping when its not.

Comment: Looking at another query issue, I thought once again about your problem. Are you in fact searching for some ResultTransformer for SQL query and DTO ? http://relation.to/Bloggers/Hibernate32TransformersForHQLAndSQL#H-SQLTransformers

Comment: @DaleBurrell: I'm running into this exact problem right now. It makes perfect sense to have a one way mapping. An ORM is an Object Relational **Mapper**. That doesn't imply that inserts, updates and deletes are supported. It's a mapping tool for relational data to object oriented data. I really wish NHibernate would allow read/select only mappings for query results. We need to load data from many other tables, and creating a view for generating a report is overkill for our scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a db view, you can use nhibernate to map to that, but if all you are doing is storing the projection fields of the query there doesn't need to be a map at all.

How are you querying this data?

if you are using the criteria API, you can use the resultstransformer to map the returned object array to your class.  the types have to match between your class that the projection.

If you are using the LINQ provider you can project directly into your class.  so you'd have something like this

```
from s in Session.Query<some-type>
where s.some-property== "some-value"
select new your-type
{
some-property-on-your-type = s.some-property,
some-other-property-on-your-type = s.some-other-property
}
```

There is no need to write a mapping to the database since you aren't mapping to an object in the database.

Comment: OK, I've edited my question to show that I'm using an sql-query, I couldn't get it to work without a mapping, but maybe that is where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should at least specify a view as the tablename of your mapping.
The view should have the same resulting columns as your query (and hopefully return any row that your query could return)

Then you will be able to :

- map your properties to your view/SQL query result columns
- set your class as mutable="false"
- declare your query as a named query (see : http://ayende.com/blog/3948/nhibernate-mapping-named-queries-query-and-sql-query )

Comment: It matter not whether you name it, because the default is the entity name. Otherwise you're correct, and thats exactly what I've done, but my question is, is there any way to tell nhibernate that its a one way mapping (see my comment on my question) as it seems wrong to be that nhibernate thinks its two way when its not. I watched in the log file as it generated an insert statement for it. Initially it also generated an update, but that was fixed by setting mutable=false which was suggested in an answer that appears to have been deleted.

Comment: @DaleBurrell : have you tried turning your id mapping  to a simple property with a column mapping, keeping unique constraint, with an insert=false and update=false (and repeat the update and insert parts for all your other properties) ?